# Get index number of a vector of structs

Tags: c, vector, struct

Is it possible to get the index of a vector of structs ?
IE I have a struct student with the members name, number and age. Lets say I have 5 students, Nelson number 2160482, Louis number 2160483, Mario number 2160484, John number 2160485 and Nicole number 2160486 . I want to get the vector's index of each student, how can I do so ?

```
typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    int number;
    int age;
} tStudents;

tStudents vStudents[];

void check_data(tStudents vStudents[], int numStudents) {
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < numStudents; n++) {
        printf("Students registered with the nr. %i:\n", vSoft[n]);//this doesnt work, any idea how to get this value ?
        printf("Name: %s\n", vStudents[n].name);
        printf("Number: %i\n", vStudents[n].number);
        printf("Age: %i\n", vStudents[n].age);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: what vector? where is it?

Comment: `this doesnt work`...please elaborate.

Comment: `vSoft[n]` is not defined anywhere in that code. Also `tStudents vStudents[];` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: You need to tell us what vSoft is, otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: Loop, count, test and break.

Comment: You need to fill `tStudents vStudents[];` with an array size. Something like `tStudents vStudents[50];`

Comment: @UnholySheep its a vector with type tStudents...this was just and exemple, thought you guys would understand what I needed with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is. You may please try the following code that I hope can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define nr 5

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int number;
    int age;
} tStudents;

tStudents vStudents[nr];

void check_data(tStudents vStudents[], int numStudents) {
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < numStudents; n++) {
        printf("Students registered with the nr. %i:\n", n);
        printf("Name: %s\n", vStudents[n].name);
        printf("Number: %i\n", vStudents[n].number);
        printf("Age: %i\n", vStudents[n].age);
    }
    getchar();
}

int main() {

    vStudents[0].name = "Nelson";
    vStudents[0].number = 2160482;
    vStudents[0].age = 12;

    vStudents[1].name = "Louis";
    vStudents[1].number = 2160483;
    vStudents[1].age = 12;

    vStudents[2].name = "Mario";
    vStudents[2].number = 2160484;
    vStudents[2].age = 12;

    vStudents[3].name = "John";
    vStudents[3].number = 2160485;
    vStudents[3].age = 12;

    vStudents[4].name = "Nicole";
    vStudents[4].number = 2160486;
    vStudents[4].age = 12;

    check_data(vStudents, nr);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Students registered with the nr. 0:
Name: Nelson
Number: 2160482
Age: 12
Students registered with the nr. 1:
Name: Louis
Number: 2160483
Age: 12
Students registered with the nr. 2:
Name: Mario
Number: 2160484
Age: 12
Students registered with the nr. 3:
Name: John
Number: 2160485
Age: 12
Students registered with the nr. 4:
Name: Nicole
Number: 2160486
Age: 12
```

Comment: yeap thats it, thank you and have a great new year !